# Custom POST request with nested params in volley returns Unexpected response code 422

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a custom GSON request, I just want to add nested params in the request. I tried different ways but it is not working, Unexpected response code 422, I am not sure where I am doing wrong. Here I am adding my code.

Custom request class

```
 public CommunicationRequest(int method, String url, Class<T> clazz,    Map<String, String> headers,
                            Response.Listener<T> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener, JSONObject json) {
    super(method, url, errorListener);
    this.clazz = clazz;
    this.listener = listener;
    this.headers = headers;
    this.json = json;
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
}

@Override
protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String json = new String(
                response.data,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        return Response.success(
                gson.fromJson(json, clazz),
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
}



@Override
protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
    listener.onResponse(response);
}

@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
    return json == null ? super.getBody() : json.toString().getBytes();
}
```

JSON format

```
{"client_id":  "",
 "client_secret": "",
 "user":{
 "email": "test123@gmail.com",
 "password": "12345678",
 "password_confirmation": "12345678", 
 "first_name": "Test",
 "last_name": "Last",
 "mobile_phones_attributes": [
    {
      "number": "1234567890",
      "type": "Mobile"
    }
]
}   
}
```

Request format

```
CommunicationRequest<DataObject> request = new CommunicationRequest<DataObject>(Request.Method.POST,
                uri,
                EmailValidObject.class, headers, this, this,params) ;
```

I am making a `JSONObject` in above json format and passing this to request.

```
JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject user = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject mob = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray mob_att = new JSONArray();
    try {
        params.put("client_id", "some_client_id");
        params.put("client_secret", "some_client_secret");
          user.put("email", "testiunn@gmail.com");
          user.put("password", "12345678");
          user.put("password_confirmation", "12345678");
          user.put("first_name", "test first");
          user.put("last_name", "test last");
             mob.put("number", "+1 (123) 122-2123");
             mob.put("type", "Mobile");
             mob_att.put(mob);
          user.put("mobile_phones_attributes", mob_att);
        params.put("user", user);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify "not working" here? Any error message available or not? Moreover, can you post source code of your server-side web service controller that processes this request?

Comment: Is server side is written in laravel

Comment: Response code 422 means "Unprocessable Entity". If the server uses this code correctly it means that it understood your request and it was well formatted, but for some reason could not be processed. You have to look into the server logs to find out why.

Comment: When I make the request from SoapUI or any external tool it is working but when I make it from Volley it is not working.

Comment: @ConvertToInt32 I think its in Ruby

Comment: Why `this, this` inside `CommunicationRequest<DataObject> request = new CommunicationRequest<DataObject>(Request.Method.POST,
                uri,
                EmailValidObject.class, headers, this, this,params);`? Moreover, if your server app available in Internet, you can use Postman to test sending request first

Comment: Because I am implementing listener in my Activity. I tried it in Postman, it is working fine not working in mobile.

Comment: @Aju did you find any solution of this issue? i am also facing the same issue

Comment: Maybe you want to send data of type is raw
[Send raw post request using volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056871/send-raw-post-request-using-volley)